# Make absolute paths relative to the project root in Webpack

Tags: webpack

I find that I need to type `../` a lot to `require()` files. My directory structure includes these:

```
js/
  components/
    ...
  actions/
    ...
```

From the components folder, I need to do `import foo from '../actions/fooAction'`. Is it possible to make the root directory the root of the project? I.e. I want to do `import foo from '/actions/fooAction'` instead. I tried setting Webpack's `resolve.root` option, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `resolve.root` option does not *modifiy* how [file modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) are resolved.

> A required module prefixed with '/' is an absolute path to the file. For example, require('/home/marco/foo.js') will load the file at /home/marco/foo.js.

The `/` resolves to the root of your file system.

Maybe what you want is to resolve your `js` folder as a [modules directory](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

**webpack.config.js**

```
resolve: {
  root: path.resolve('./js')
}
```

With this configuration added to your config file will tell webpack to resolve any `import` or `require` relative to your `js` folder. Then, instead of using

```
import foo from '../actions/fooAction'
```

you will be able to:

```
import foo from 'actions/fooAction`
```

Mind the lack of `/` at the beginning.

Comment: There are (what feels like) hundreds of Stack Overflow questions all asking essentially this same thing, along with tens of different Webpack documentation pages and NONE OF THEM explain this incredibly simple concept even half as clearly as you just did.  Thank you (and a pox on the Webpack people for making so hard to find this answer)!

Comment: Can it simply be set to './' and have everything relative to the project root folder?

Comment: @JoeTidee - no, that's relative to the current file

Comment: `resolve['root']` takes an array now: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#resolveroot

Comment: It seems that as of September 2020 webpack do not support `root` option any more, now you need to pass an array to `resolve.modules` option — `resolve: { modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'] }`

Comment: @DmitrySokurenko For what it's worth, the webpack `root` option has been eliminated in favor of a [`roots` (plural) option that can accept multiple roots](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveroots).

`roots` serves a different purpose than `modules` in that it changes how _absolute_ paths are resolved.

Answer (score 16):

I am going to answer this slightly differently without using resolve.root. Everything @dresyecat said is correct. However, I just went through the same exercise of moving from relative paths everywhere to module paths. [Here is the doc](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/) that explains the three different types of paths you can use in the import statement.

You are asking to use a module path, which I believe is the preferred way to go.

The problem is that by default, module paths only work with things imported via npm because the new *modules* variable on resolve defaults to ["node_modules"]. This lets you import 3rd party code from npm really easily. But it means importing your code with a module path needs a config change. BTW, the *modules* used to be called *moduleDirectories* in previous versions. [Here are the docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) for the resolve variable configuration.

Ok assuming you have a directory structure like this:

```
project/
    webpack.config.json
    js/
        components
        actions
```

You can set the modules directory to be:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js', '*' ],
    modules: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "js"), "node_modules"]
}
```

A couple important points:

- Be sure to include the "node_modules" if you are using npm to pull in 3rd party code, or your imports of those will start to fail
- Be sure to import the path component in your configuration so that path is defined

  var path = require('path');

Then you can use the following (as was pointed out - without the leading /) to import your components using the module path form:

```
import "actions/fooAction";
```

Comment: anno 2023, this is the only right answer. I was using angular (I know, I had to for an older project) together with webpack.

Answer (score 4):

The resolving process is basically simple and distinguishes between three variants:

> **absolute path:** require("/home/me/file")
>
> **relative path:** require("../src/file") or require("./file")
>
> **module path**: require("module/lib/file")

## The first two are pretty obvious, the third deserves a closer look:

1. Absolute to your filesystem indeed
2. Relative to the current file (if that file is in `src/foo/bar` or `webpack/config/subconfig`, then indeed that's it...)
3. In contrast to `import` (which handles 1+2 pretty much the same way, but would send you looking in `node_modules` right away)  path 'module' indeed means your project root for paths without a need to resolve, like `output.path` in your webpack config...  and: (on resolving) **Only 3 is subject to `resolve.root` and `resolve.moduleDirectories` resolving, [see webpack docs here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html#resolving-a-module-path)**

Comment: Helpful explanation, thanks! That should be in the docs. There's also resolving _directories_ (see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemainfiles), but that may be orthogonal and be subject to those same 3 categories too.

Answer (score 4):

Other solution is using [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) to import *js* like a module (I'm not saying that it's a module, just the syntax is similar).

```js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    js: path.resolve(__dirname, './js'),
  },
}
```

And you can import `fooAction` this way:

```js
import foo from 'js/actions/fooAction';
```

Answer (score 2):

now you should use

```
resolve: {
    roots: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'components'),
    ],
},
```

see more https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveroots

Answer (score 1):

With Webpack 5 you have to add the following lines into your webpack.config.js file:

```
resolve: {
   modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules']
}
```